# How to outline in one way for each variables selected a graph with normality distribution

Tags: r, graph, normal-distribution

[image]I was trying to perform a normality distribution test on a series of specific variables of the dataset I'm working on and I've coded the followings commands

```
as.data.frame(d) %>% 
      dplyr::select(
        age, T1.rt, CR.rt) %>% 
      na.omit() %>% 
      apply(., 2, ad.test)
```

However, I do not know how to enter also a command for outline in one way for each variables I've selected the histograms with nomrality distribution with normality curve included. Specifically, the histogram code I'm instrested in should have the following hallmarks:

Taking the variable 'age'

```
windows(width=7, height=7); par(lwd=1, las=1, family="sans", cex=1, 
  mgp=c(3.0,1,0))
hist2(d$age, freq=F, main="", xlab="age", ylab="", col="darkgray")
curve(dnorm(x, mean=mean(d$age[!is.na(d$age)]), 
  sd=sd(d$age[!is.na(d$age)])), add=T)
skewness.kurtosis(d$age)
ks.test(d$age, "pnorm", mean=mean(d$age[!is.na(d$age)]), 
  sd=sd(d$age[!is.na(d$age)]))
```

I'm just reporting here some of the observation of the dataset I'm working on:

```
dput(head(d,50))
structure(list(ID = c("P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
"P1323", "P1323", "P1323"), gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), age = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19), fixation_time = c(60, 
60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 70, 50, 
70, 70, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 60, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 60, 70, 50, 
60, 70, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 70, 50, 60, 50, 60, 60, 70, 50, 60, 
60), block = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), t1.key = c("None", "None", 
"None", "space", "None", "space", "None", "None", "None", "space", 
"None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", 
"space", "None", "space", "space", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
"space", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "None", "None", "space", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
"None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "space", "None"
), T1.response = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), COND = c("NR", 
"NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", 
"R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "R", "R", "NR", 
"NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
"NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", 
"R", "NR", "R", "NR"), T1.rt = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.812299799988978, 
NA, 0.72336569998879, NA, NA, NA, 0.772733500052709, NA, NA, 
0.606754800013732, NA, NA, 0.601030899968464, NA, NA, 0.838272600027267, 
NA, 0.305548300035298, 0.849945599969942, 0.748269900039304, 
NA, NA, NA, 0.859215400007088, 0.95704890001798, NA, NA, 0.874362500035204, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.270455699996091, 0.75726039998699, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.762694000033662, NA, NA, 0.789715700026136, 
NA, 0.90579859999707, NA), CR.key = c("p", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
"p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "o", "p", "i", "i", 
"h", "u", "i", "u", "o", "o", "p", "p", "p", "o", "p", "i", "o", 
"p", "p", "p", "o", "o", "o", "p", "i", "p", "p", "o", "o", "i", 
"i", "o", "o", "i", "i", "u"), CR.rt = c(0.651771800010465, 0.585048799985088, 
0.652350199990906, 0.69888829998672, 1.01917029998731, 0.550036200031173, 
0.0361186999944039, 0.568817299965303, 0.452191599993966, 0.514980700041633, 
0.619590600021184, 0.719264700019266, 0.466181399999186, 0.45217840000987, 
0.668881699966732, 0.914478300022893, 1.01910460001091, 1.40315000002738, 
1.69993370003067, 1.71914210001705, 1.29938790004235, 0.698139799991623, 
0.848338100011461, 0.651829700043891, 0.486136299965438, 0.703567499993369, 
0.76673849998042, 0.54929809999885, 0.718664799991529, 0.768383099988569, 
0.898415500007104, 0.819344500021543, 0.61898209998617, 0.737225699995179, 
1.03654629999073, 0.971092400024645, 1.4362695000018, 0.999490200018045, 
0.932840399967972, 0.586312200000975, 0.786785800009966, 1.01987839996582, 
0.93673920002766, 0.715710600023158, 0.819960499997251, 0.75370900001144, 
0.818668299994897, 0.903600800025742, 1.1176545000053, 1.10352450003847
), trial_num = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 
33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 
50, 51, 52, 53), ldots = c(48, 48, 52, 55, 51, 51, 52, 49, 45, 
55, 49, 49, 51, 49, 48, 52, 45, 49, 45, 55, 51, 48, 55, 51, 45, 
45, 52, 48, 48, 48, 55, 51, 49, 48, 49, 51, 51, 55, 51, 49, 45, 
55, 51, 55, 55, 52, 52, 48, 49, 52), rdots = c(52, 52, 48, 45, 
49, 49, 48, 51, 55, 45, 51, 51, 49, 51, 52, 48, 55, 51, 55, 45, 
49, 52, 45, 49, 55, 55, 48, 52, 52, 52, 45, 49, 51, 52, 51, 49, 
49, 45, 49, 51, 55, 45, 49, 45, 45, 48, 48, 52, 51, 48), TASK = c("left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
"left"), T1.correct = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Go.Nogo..whether.a.person.should.respond. = c("NR", 
"NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", 
"NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "R", "R", 
"NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"NR", "NR", "R"), T1.ACC = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), CR = c(4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 9, 1, 2, 1, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), difficulty = c("medium", "medium", "medium", 
"easy", "hard", "hard", "medium", "hard", "easy", "easy", "hard", 
"hard", "hard", "hard", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", 
"easy", "hard", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", "easy", "medium", 
"medium", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "hard", "medium", 
"hard", "hard", "hard", "easy", "hard", "hard", "easy", "easy", 
"hard", "easy", "easy", "medium", "medium", "medium", "hard", 
"medium")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Has anyone any clue? How should I keep on the afprementioned code? Furthermore I would like that the graphs might plotted together in the same window, not overlapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now, having your data, we can do it again.

1. We load your data

```
df=structure(list(ID = c("P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", "P1323", 
 "P1323", "P1323", "P1323"), gender = c("F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
 "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
 "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
 "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
 "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), age = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19), fixation_time = c(60, 
 60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 70, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 70, 50, 
 70, 70, 60, 70, 50, 50, 50, 60, 70, 60, 50, 60, 70, 60, 70, 50, 
 60, 70, 50, 50, 70, 70, 70, 70, 50, 60, 50, 60, 60, 70, 50, 60, 
 60), block = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), t1.key = c("None", "None", 
 "None", "space", "None", "space", "None", "None", "None", "space", 
 "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", 
 "space", "None", "space", "space", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
 "space", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
 "None", "None", "None", "space", "space", "None", "None", "None", 
 "None", "space", "None", "None", "space", "None", "space", "None"
 ), T1.response = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), COND = c("NR", 
 "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", 
 "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "R", "R", "R", "NR", 
 "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
 "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", 
 "R", "NR", "R", "NR"), T1.rt = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.812299799988978, 
 NA, 0.72336569998879, NA, NA, NA, 0.772733500052709, NA, NA, 
 0.606754800013732, NA, NA, 0.601030899968464, NA, NA, 0.838272600027267, 
 NA, 0.305548300035298, 0.849945599969942, 0.748269900039304, 
 NA, NA, NA, 0.859215400007088, 0.95704890001798, NA, NA, 0.874362500035204, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.270455699996091, 0.75726039998699, 
 NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.762694000033662, NA, NA, 0.789715700026136, 
 NA, 0.90579859999707, NA), CR.key = c("p", "p", "p", "p", "p", 
 "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "p", "o", "p", "i", "i", 
 "h", "u", "i", "u", "o", "o", "p", "p", "p", "o", "p", "i", "o", 
 "p", "p", "p", "o", "o", "o", "p", "i", "p", "p", "o", "o", "i", 
 "i", "o", "o", "i", "i", "u"), CR.rt = c(0.651771800010465, 0.585048799985088, 
 0.652350199990906, 0.69888829998672, 1.01917029998731, 0.550036200031173, 
 0.0361186999944039, 0.568817299965303, 0.452191599993966, 0.514980700041633, 
 0.619590600021184, 0.719264700019266, 0.466181399999186, 0.45217840000987, 
 0.668881699966732, 0.914478300022893, 1.01910460001091, 1.40315000002738, 
 1.69993370003067, 1.71914210001705, 1.29938790004235, 0.698139799991623, 
 0.848338100011461, 0.651829700043891, 0.486136299965438, 0.703567499993369, 
 0.76673849998042, 0.54929809999885, 0.718664799991529, 0.768383099988569, 
 0.898415500007104, 0.819344500021543, 0.61898209998617, 0.737225699995179, 
 1.03654629999073, 0.971092400024645, 1.4362695000018, 0.999490200018045, 
 0.932840399967972, 0.586312200000975, 0.786785800009966, 1.01987839996582, 
 0.93673920002766, 0.715710600023158, 0.819960499997251, 0.75370900001144, 
 0.818668299994897, 0.903600800025742, 1.1176545000053, 1.10352450003847
 ), trial_num = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
 14, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 
 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 47, 48, 49, 
 50, 51, 52, 53), ldots = c(48, 48, 52, 55, 51, 51, 52, 49, 45, 
 55, 49, 49, 51, 49, 48, 52, 45, 49, 45, 55, 51, 48, 55, 51, 45, 
 45, 52, 48, 48, 48, 55, 51, 49, 48, 49, 51, 51, 55, 51, 49, 45, 
 55, 51, 55, 55, 52, 52, 48, 49, 52), rdots = c(52, 52, 48, 45, 
 49, 49, 48, 51, 55, 45, 51, 51, 49, 51, 52, 48, 55, 51, 55, 45, 
 49, 52, 45, 49, 55, 55, 48, 52, 52, 52, 45, 49, 51, 52, 51, 49, 
 49, 45, 49, 51, 55, 45, 49, 45, 45, 48, 48, 52, 51, 48), TASK = c("left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", "left", 
 "left"), T1.correct = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Go.Nogo..whether.a.person.should.respond. = c("NR", 
 "NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", 
 "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "R", "R", 
 "NR", "NR", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "NR", 
 "R", "R", "R", "R", "NR", "NR", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
 "NR", "NR", "R"), T1.ACC = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), CR = c(4, 
 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 2, 9, 1, 2, 1, 
 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), difficulty = c("medium", "medium", "medium", 
 "easy", "hard", "hard", "medium", "hard", "easy", "easy", "hard", 
 "hard", "hard", "hard", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", 
 "easy", "hard", "medium", "easy", "hard", "easy", "easy", "medium", 
 "medium", "medium", "medium", "easy", "hard", "hard", "medium", 
 "hard", "hard", "hard", "easy", "hard", "hard", "easy", "easy", 
 "hard", "easy", "easy", "medium", "medium", "medium", "hard", 
 "medium")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
 "data.frame"))
```

2. Now we will change their representation so that the lines contain individual variable names and data (`tibble` in `tibble`)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.numeric), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  nest()
```

output df1

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   variable [12]
   variable      data             
   <chr>         <list>           
 1 age           <tibble [50 x 9]>
 2 fixation_time <tibble [50 x 9]>
 3 block         <tibble [50 x 9]>
 4 T1.response   <tibble [50 x 9]>
 5 T1.rt         <tibble [50 x 9]>
 6 CR.rt         <tibble [50 x 9]>
 7 trial_num     <tibble [50 x 9]>
 8 ldots         <tibble [50 x 9]>
 9 rdots         <tibble [50 x 9]>
10 T1.correct    <tibble [50 x 9]>
11 T1.ACC        <tibble [50 x 9]>
12 CR            <tibble [50 x 9]>
```

What is such a `tibble` in `tibble`? Let's check.

```
df1$data[[6]] %>% select(ID, value)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 50 x 2
   ID     value
   <chr>  <dbl>
 1 P1323 0.652 
 2 P1323 0.585 
 3 P1323 0.652 
 4 P1323 0.699 
 5 P1323 1.02  
 6 P1323 0.550 
 7 P1323 0.0361
 8 P1323 0.569 
 9 P1323 0.452 
10 P1323 0.515 
# ... with 40 more rows
```

Well, since we have data in separate `tibble`, let's create a function that returns the statistics we are interested in.

```
add.statistic = function(data) {
  x = data$value[!is.na(data$value)] 
  suppressWarnings(tibble(
    n = length(x),
    nunique = length(unique(x)),
    mean = mean(x),
    sd = sd(x),
    skew = ifelse(nunique>1,moments::skewness(x), NA),
    kur = ifelse(nunique>1,moments::kurtosis(x), NA),
    ks.p = ifelse(nunique>1,stats::ks.test(x, "pnorm", mean, sd)$p.value, NA),
    ad.stat = ifelse(nunique>1,nortest::ad.test(x)$statistic, NA),
    ad.p = ifelse(nunique>1,nortest::ad.test(x)$p.value, NA),
    sw.stat = ifelse(nunique>1,stats::shapiro.test(x)$statistic, NA),
    sw.p = ifelse(nunique>1,stats::shapiro.test(x)$p.value, NA)
  ))
}
```

A few comments are needed here. Variables can contain all the same values. Then counting statistics like `skewness`, `kurtosis`, `shapiro` and the like is pointless. For this I added the `ifelse` function and the `nunique` variable there.

Furthermore, the test `ks.test` may generate warnings. For this I used `suppressWarnings` to silence it.

Now let's see how our `add.statistic` function works

```
add.statistic(df1$data[[6]])
```

output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
      n nunique  mean    sd  skew   kur  ks.p ad.stat    ad.p sw.stat    sw.p
  <int>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    50      50 0.818 0.313 0.849  4.53 0.456    1.17 0.00421   0.928 0.00465
```

Bingo! We have statistics!
Let's put it together now.

```
df1 = df %>% 
  pivot_longer(where(is.numeric), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(stat = map(data, add.statistic)) 

df1 %>%  unnest(stat)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 13
# Groups:   variable [12]
   variable      data                  n nunique   mean     sd    skew   kur          ks.p ad.stat      ad.p sw.stat      sw.p
   <chr>         <list>            <int>   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 age           <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       1 19      0     NA      NA    NA             NA     NA         NA     NA       
 2 fixation_time <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       3 60.4    8.07  -0.0719  1.57  0.0139         3.90   7.17e-10   0.799  8.36e- 7
 3 block         <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       1  0      0     NA      NA    NA             NA     NA         NA     NA       
 4 T1.response   <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       2  0.34   0.479  0.676   1.46  0.0000000391  10.1    3.7 e-24   0.599  1.85e-10
 5 T1.rt         <tibble [50 x 9]>    17      17  0.731  0.191 -1.42    4.15  0.209          1.20   2.74e- 3   0.819  3.78e- 3
 6 CR.rt         <tibble [50 x 9]>    50      50  0.818  0.313  0.849   4.53  0.456          1.17   4.21e- 3   0.928  4.65e- 3
 7 trial_num     <tibble [50 x 9]>    50      50 26.5   16.0   -0.0204  1.78  0.854          0.582  1.23e- 1   0.952  4.28e- 2
 8 ldots         <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       6 50.2    3.05   0.0230  2.28  0.297          1.27   2.35e- 3   0.918  2.06e- 3
 9 rdots         <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       6 49.8    3.05  -0.0230  2.28  0.297          1.27   2.35e- 3   0.918  2.06e- 3
10 T1.correct    <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       2  0.52   0.505 -0.0801  1.01  0.0000101      8.84   8.98e-22   0.636  6.99e-10
11 T1.ACC        <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       2  0.66   0.479 -0.676   1.46  0.0000000391  10.1    3.7 e-24   0.599  1.85e-10
12 CR            <tibble [50 x 9]>    50       5  3.32   1.25   1.39    9.82  0.00112        3.66   2.77e- 9   0.755  9.19e- 8
```

Everything works great. So let's create a function that generates the graph. However, only for variables for which `nunique`> 1!

```
create.plot = function(df, group){
  stat = df$stat[[1]]
  data = df$data[[1]]
  hist.val = hist(data$value, 30)
  if(stat$nunique ==1) return(NULL)
  statlab = stat %>%
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "stat", values_to = "val") %>%
    mutate(x=hist.val$breaks[2],
           y=seq(max(hist.val$density)*0.1,
                 max(hist.val$density)*0.7,
                 length.out=length(stat)),
           lab = paste(stat,":",signif(val,3)))
  data %>% ggplot(aes(value))+
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), colour="black", fill="white")+
    geom_density(alpha=.2, fill="red", col="red")+
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = stat$mean, sd = stat$sd),
                  col="blue")+
    geom_label(data=statlab, aes(x=x, y=y, label = lab))+
    xlab(group)
}
```

Let's check how our `create.plot` function works on the selected variable

```
create.plot(df1[6,], df1[6,1])
```

[image]

I don't know if you exactly expected it, but I assume you might like such a plot.

Now all we have to do is combine everything together in one neat command

```
df1 %>% group_by(variable) %>% 
  group_map(create.plot)
```

Below are some selected charts
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think I have removed it. In case just let me notified it, please.

Comment: Dear Marek Fiołka, your codes seems pretty good, but I would try to run it for checking out if that makes the one I've been looking for. Actaully I'm the following error:  Error in 
 UseMethod("pivot_longer") : 
  no applicable method for 'pivot_longer' applied to an object of class "function" when I tried running the code frame after showing how the add.statistic function works.

Comment: Check what version of the `tidyverse` package you have. I have 1.3.1. I checked my program again and everything works fine.

Remember that on Stack Overflow you thank you for accepting the correct solution. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and installing it again but I'm keeping on getting back the same problem.

Comment: What if you just run such a command `df%>%
   pivot_longer (where (is.numeric), names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") `?

Comment: it's exactly the same, unfortunately.

Comment: Run `class (df)` and write what the output is

Comment: class (df)
[1] "function"

Comment: And that is the answer to your problem! You did not run my first block of code `df = structure (list (ID = c (" P1323 ", .....`

Comment: ok, thanks. But actually that is just a sample with 50 observations. I would need to run this function on the complete dataset

Comment: Exactly! Put all the data in `df` and run the code. That's all you have to do.

Comment: I was able to solve that, but when I run create.plot(df1[6,], df1[6,1]), I obtain: 
Error: Assigned data `eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 9 rows.
x Assigned data has 11 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.

Comment: ` df1 %>% head(1) - A tibble: 1 x 3 Groups:   variable [1]  variable data  stat            
  <chr>    <list>                <list>          
1 age      <tbl_df [41,713 x 9]> <tbl_df [1 x 9]>`

Comment: ALL RIGHT. I think I know where the problem is. It looks like you removed some statistics from the `add.statistic`  function. Originally this function returns 11 statistics. You clearly have only 9 (`<tbl_df [1 x 9]>`). This was the cause! I have already improved the chart function so that it is not sensitive to the amount of statistics. I just changed `length.out = 11` to `length.out = length (stat)`. Everything should work fine now.

Comment: I had to. The shapiro.test could be run just on the sample between 3 and 5000 and the original length is >5000

Comment: If everything works now, I'd appreciate accepting the solution!

Comment: It doesn't actually. On the complete dataset there are more than 5000 observation. So with the code above that turns out as an error when it tries to put some statistics out.

Comment: Woow! I am amazed! Do you really think my answer doesn't answer your question ?!
Do you really think that from the content of your question I should infer how big of a dataset you are operating?
Do you really think that I should show you how to deal with such a trivial problem as vectort size control? You can't write something like `ifelse (nunique> 1 & length (x)> 3 & length (x) <5000, stats :: shapiro.test (x) $ statistic, NA)` or any other formula that would suit your needs?
I suggest that you mark my answer as inappropriate and bother me more.

Comment: do you think do I to modify the function you've used to answer to my question on graph for pairwise comparisons for computing the Shapiro-Wilk test together with this plot? Because it escapes of mind how to implement it on a nested dataframe like the one I'm using now. Just let me know when you can reply back. If you need, here the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69528926/how-to-print-on-a-serie-sof-graphs-pairwise-comparisons-bars-and-effect-size-val