# How to print on a serie sof graphs pairwise comparisons bars and effect size value?

Tags: r, loops, boxplot, pairwise

I'm struggling to create a series of high-quality ggboxplots, like the one I attach as follows:

[image]

1. With labels for ANOVA with F(df) test value, p.value and effects size
2. With multi-pairwose comparisons bars with bars and stars with significant difference.

Statistics for post-hocs comparisons have been obtained for the example above in the way you could find following [this link page](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/) and I've run the following code

```
#Compute the post-hocs
postHocs <- df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(., -c(A, C, D),'s')%>%
  mutate(s = fct_relevel(s, 
                               c("E", "F", "G", 
                                 "H", "I", "J", 
                                 "K", "L", "M", 
                                 "N", "O", "P")) %>% 
  arrange(s) %>%
  group_by(s) %>% 
  pairwise_t_test(
    value ~ D, paired = TRUE,
    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
  ) %>% 
  #dplyr::select(., -'s')%>% 
  print()
```

while the Anova statistics have been obtained:

```
    res.aov <- df %>% 
      tidyr::pivot_longer(., -c(A, C, D),'s')%>%
      mutate(s = fct_relevel(s,c("E", "F", "G", 
                                 "H", "I", "J", 
                                 "K", "L", "M", 
                                 "N", "O", "P") 
                                   )))%>% 
      arrange(s) %>%
      group_by(s) %>% 
      anova_test(., value ~ D, dv = value, wid = A, within = D)%>% 
      print()
```

from which I've tried to obtain the interested statistics with this code:

```
unnested_aov <- lapply(res.aov$anova, `[[`, 1)
```

I scripted this for loop to adding the statistics to graphs

```
comparisons <- postHocs %>% add_xy_position(x = "D")
comparisons

for (i in 5:ncol(df)) {
  bxp <- ggboxplot(df,
                   x = 'D', y = colnames(df[i]))
  print(
    bxp +   stat_pvalue_manual(comparisons[,i]) +
      labs(
        subtitle = get_test_label(unnested_aov[[i]], detailed = TRUE),
        caption = get_pwc_label(comparisons[,i])))
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Since I'm getting back some error, I thing that the problem is that 'comparison' contains 36 rows and length does not fit well the number of the graph I should obtain (12).

I'll let you here the code below and I'll be open to your best suggestion in this concern.

Thank you

```
structure(list(A = 1:20, C = c("Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", 
"Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", 
"Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", "Maybe", 
"Maybe", "Maybe"), D = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("new_value_for_8", 
"new_value_for_6", "new_value_for_4"), class = "factor"), E = c(988.368784828308, 
988.856158671407, 996.004085290553, 999.685844324618, 1000.23888564896, 
1005.03749946898, 999.786378084971, 997.039675082569, 998.028313183065, 
997.168905747014, 1001.09291198164, 993.307008354785, 1004.23849942428, 
1002.98988896299, 1003.55106999008, 1009.57481668809, 1005.41677956183, 
1001.70676077155, 993.869639239065, 997.170442654021), F = c(994.834756009939, 
994.468875098246, 1000.62150212342, 1002.23100741241, 1003.96990710863, 
1007.75899775608, 998.699806256246, 996.401009591011, 998.076594704249, 
1002.19344184533, 1005.87900720863, 994.076210622421, 1002.44958531768, 
1003.10043497883, 1001.65779442628, 1013.71182331817, 1006.86178446511, 
1005.31481098188, 995.867593313022, 1000.16218228559), G = c(1011.88022669726, 
1012.10534266625, 1012.9554415821, 1015.09810043606, 1015.40462298842, 
1016.67103699915, 1003.13771453335, 999.9107434841, 1002.15365554737, 
1013.67789244066, 1014.38627383064, 1006.86762877786, 1007.47946451329, 
1008.93405130319, 1008.45962311068, 1023.4166601996, 1015.18680921429, 
1009.97183712754, 1006.2675210718, 1010.14219845841), H = c(988.221495702721, 
990.850727928741, 992.418094914622, 995.984841639886, 993.398346143465, 
997.971380355398, 1004.4672957051, 1002.54036572775, 1002.2292388993, 
999.116379988893, 997.364309124077, 997.937032776913, 1001.14544537612, 
1002.08056674659, 1000.0422658299, 1013.29862597967, 1005.06669915366, 
1003.93467692475, 1000.02290694207, 1004.31923128858), I = c(994.035709684742, 
994.890815628412, 997.18267770374, 998.564426335124, 996.851278420874, 
1000.16039368502, 1003.52155765272, 1002.1043798945, 1002.7069399281, 
1005.49897156208, 1005.81171180245, 998.62698748611, 999.56563615154, 
1002.87987510596, 998.728473297166, 1017.2093269366, 1007.79412746756, 
1008.11964589961, 1004.9525336386, 1009.50695673265), J = c(1008.23981597718, 
1009.51261484649, 1009.42367409926, 1005.06332653216, 1005.02619159395, 
1009.07903916629, 1007.56089165218, 1005.49719893791, 1004.91476855238, 
1013.03209535721, 1010.84145164945, 1005.86927622259, 1003.25309970443, 
1004.68478802971, 1002.71096740085, 1025.56743956652, 1016.32418136177, 
1013.09901927997, 1011.92002817369, 1014.69013052771), K = c(994.327042030287, 
995.608170991922, 997.033470393412, 1000.15918365269, 998.216388150646, 
1001.97377908784, 1003.17401220482, 1001.60211665164, 1002.27932356239, 
1002.41479226363, 999.832076213262, 1001.37236796086, 1001.17012593697, 
1001.40362599894, 999.964771265342, 1012.75282463779, 1008.65746780516, 
1005.290878105, 999.464067607865, 1005.14963479715), L = c(999.225538268699, 
999.349990537239, 1001.14010250645, 1001.51403741206, 1000.25571835554, 
1003.76051565494, 1002.74763442988, 1001.09116707486, 1003.29833843754, 
1006.55857216695, 1007.06029312947, 1000.60539548502, 999.637387760292, 
1002.72729847885, 998.034039799405, 1016.5065564384, 1009.68783611392, 
1009.47863905986, 1003.56318544047, 1009.23934223585), M = c(1009.99385579756, 
1011.12126521731, 1010.6989716872, 1003.7899021821, 1004.59413830322, 
1008.52123662618, 1006.34418311104, 1004.1077131243, 1004.94124365003, 
1011.89121961563, 1010.13326381032, 1005.33467168056, 1001.04545904874, 
1002.86650202467, 1000.45601490752, 1022.13789464831, 1016.25544969107, 
1012.37379951646, 1008.53744587416, 1012.00856171947), N = c(999.801263745036, 
996.838989582336, 1000.89599227983, 1003.11042068113, 1002.27800090558, 
1003.83846437952, 1000.70169995102, 1001.75290674649, 998.660833714301, 
1006.69246804854, 1004.7636391085, 1005.63873342951, 1001.37744267414, 
1000.97339668679, 1001.98775658049, 1004.70492544978, 1012.11738595707, 
1001.0458886613, 996.725751886115, 1003.17906097432), O = c(1002.96437294923, 
997.870867692911, 1002.94619035116, 1003.44844607015, 1003.02403433836, 
1004.70457675466, 999.880559826981, 1000.66826545719, 999.59436981446, 
1007.32640154038, 1006.7506344557, 1001.59973104217, 1000.71689406196, 
1001.15587576193, 999.988638552344, 1006.4489695839, 1010.51785193511, 
1003.79329103591, 999.118472788132, 1004.99936090838), P = c(1006.28027312932, 
1005.24535230967, 1007.68162285336, 1001.08242973466, 1002.99896314, 
1005.36085942954, 1001.22060069797, 1000.43007709819, 1000.47666761108, 
1008.73650967215, 1007.20593389744, 1004.57722295264, 998.66379615346, 
998.711140983915, 999.452420534917, 1008.11715753014, 1013.30601537204, 
1002.03237948844, 1002.88799699943, 1005.57921718108)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The function `pairwise_t_test` comes from what package?

Comment: The package is rstatix

Comment: Look at the line of your code: `unnested_aov <- lapply(res.aov$anova, `[[`, 1)`. The object `res.aov$anova` does not exist!

Comment: If you try running all the code as I wrote it should be turned back (anova_test() function creates it).

Comment: The line `unnested_aov <- lapply(res.aov$anova, [[, 1)` produces the following warning: `Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: anova`. Moreover, `res.aov` does not have column `anova`.

Comment: May you stick here the output you obtain after giving the print()?

Comment: The following `tibble`: `# A tibble: 12 × 8
   signals     Effect   DFn   DFd     F     p `p<.05`   ges
 * <fct>       <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1 P3FCz       COND       2     2 29.1  0.033 "*"     0.235
 2 P3Cz        COND       2     2 22.7  0.042 "*"     0.28 `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This takes a bit more work.
Let's start with data preparation

```
#Loading libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(readxl)

#Upload data
df_join <- read_excel("df_join.xlsx")

df = df_join  %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ID:COND), factor) %>%
  pivot_longer(P3FCz:LPP2Pz, names_to = "signals") %>%
  group_by(signals) %>%
  nest()

#Let's see what we have here
df
df$data[[1]]
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   signals [12]
   signals     data             
   <chr>       <list>           
 1 P3FCz       <tibble [75 x 5]>
 2 P3Cz        <tibble [75 x 5]>
 3 P3Pz        <tibble [75 x 5]>
 4 LPPearlyFCz <tibble [75 x 5]>
 5 LPPearlyCz  <tibble [75 x 5]>
 6 LPPearlyPz  <tibble [75 x 5]>
 7 LPP1FCz     <tibble [75 x 5]>
 8 LPP1Cz      <tibble [75 x 5]>
 9 LPP1Pz      <tibble [75 x 5]>
10 LPP2FCz     <tibble [75 x 5]>
11 LPP2Cz      <tibble [75 x 5]>
12 LPP2Pz      <tibble [75 x 5]>
> df$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 75 x 5
   ID    GR    SES   COND      value
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>     <dbl>
 1 01    RP    V     NEG-CTR -11.6  
 2 01    RP    V     NEG-NOC -11.1  
 3 01    RP    V     NEU-NOC  -4.00 
 4 04    RP    V     NEG-CTR  -0.314
 5 04    RP    V     NEG-NOC   0.239
 6 04    RP    V     NEU-NOC   5.04 
 7 06    RP    V     NEG-CTR  -0.214
 8 06    RP    V     NEG-NOC  -2.96 
 9 06    RP    V     NEU-NOC  -1.97 
10 07    RP    V     NEG-CTR  -2.83 
# ... with 65 more rows
```

Now we have to prepare functions that will return us some statistics

```
#Preparation of functions for statistics
ShapiroTest = function(d, alpha=0.05){
  st = list(statistic = NA, p.value = NA, test = FALSE)
  if(length(d)>5000) d=sample(d, 5000)
  if(length(d)>=3 & length(d)<=5000){
    sw = shapiro.test(d)
    st$statistic = sw$statistic
    st$p.value = sw$p.value
    st$test = sw$p.value>alpha
  }
  return(st)
}

sum_stats = function(data, group, value, alpha=0.05)data %>%
  group_by(!!enquo(group)) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n(),
    q1 = quantile(!!enquo(value),1/4,8),
    min = min(!!enquo(value)),
    mean = mean(!!enquo(value)),
    median = median(!!enquo(value)),
    q3 = quantile(!!enquo(value),3/4,8),
    max = max(!!enquo(value)),
    sd = sd(!!enquo(value)),
    kurtosis = e1071::kurtosis(!!enquo(value)),
    skewness = e1071::skewness(!!enquo(value)),
    SW.stat = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$statistic,
    SW.p = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$p.value,
    SW.test = ShapiroTest(!!enquo(value), alpha)$test,
    nout = length(boxplot.stats(!!enquo(value))$out)
  )

#Using the sum stats function
df$data[[1]] %>% sum_stats(COND, value)

df %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  mutate(stats = map(data, ~sum_stats(.x, COND, value))) %>%
  unnest(stats)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 36 x 17
# Groups:   signals [12]
   signals     data        COND      n    q1     min   mean median     q3   max    sd kurtosis skewness SW.stat  SW.p SW.test  nout
   <chr>       <list>      <fct> <int> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   <int>
 1 P3FCz       <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25 -5.73 -11.6   -1.59  -1.83   1.86   9.57  4.93   -0.612   0.128    0.984 0.951 TRUE        0
 2 P3FCz       <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25 -4.14 -11.1   -1.39  -0.522  0.659  8.16  4.44   -0.169  -0.211    0.978 0.842 TRUE        1
 3 P3FCz       <tibble [7~ NEU-~    25 -5.35  -6.97  -1.48  -1.97   1.89   6.24  4.00   -1.28    0.189    0.943 0.174 TRUE        0
 4 P3Cz        <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25 -2.76  -8.16   0.313  0.906  2.45  13.7   4.58    0.867   0.622    0.952 0.277 TRUE        1
 5 P3Cz        <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25 -2.22  -9.23   0.739  0.545  3.10  14.5   4.78    1.05    0.527    0.963 0.477 TRUE        1
 6 P3Cz        <tibble [7~ NEU-~    25 -4.14  -6.07  -0.107  0.622  2.16   7.76  3.88   -1.09    0.0112   0.957 0.359 TRUE        0
 7 P3Pz        <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25  5.66  -0.856  8.79   7.48  11.9   23.4   5.22    0.502   0.673    0.961 0.436 TRUE        1
 8 P3Pz        <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25  3.86  -0.888  8.45   7.88  11.2   20.7   5.23   -0.530   0.206    0.982 0.924 TRUE        0
 9 P3Pz        <tibble [7~ NEU-~    25  2.30  -0.932  6.43   6.82   8.46  16.7   4.60   -0.740   0.373    0.968 0.588 TRUE        0
10 LPPearlyFCz <tibble [7~ NEG-~    25 -4.02 -11.8   -0.666  0.149  1.90  13.3   5.02    0.916   0.202    0.947 0.215 TRUE        1
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Next we need to analyze the QQ charts. To do this, let's prepare the appropriate functions.

```
#function that creates a QQ plot
SignalQQPlot = function(data, signal, autor = "G. Anonim") data %>%
  group_by(COND) %>%
  mutate(label = paste("\nSW p-value:" ,
                       signif(shapiro.test(value)$p.value, 3))) %>%
  ggqqplot("value", facet.by = "COND") %>%
  ggpar(title = paste("QQ plots for", signal, "signal"),
        caption = autor)+
  geom_label(aes(x=0, y=+Inf, label=label))

#QQ plot for the P3FCz signal
df$data[[1]] %>% SignalQQPlot("P3FCz")

#A function that creates a QQ plot and adds it to a data frame
AddSignalQQPlot = function(df, signal, printPlot=TRUE) {
  plot = SignalQQPlot(df$data[[1]], signal)
  if(printPlot) print(plot)
  df %>% mutate(qqplot = list(plot))
}

#Added QQ charts
df %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  group_modify(~AddSignalQQPlot(.x, .y))
```

Correct the author's name.
[image]

Now we will add statistics from ANOVA and tTest

```
#Add ANOVA test value
fAddANOVA = function(data) data %>% 
  anova_test(value~COND) %>% as_tibble()

#Method 1
df %>% group_by(signals) %>% 
  group_modify(~fAddANOVA(.x$data[[1]]))

#Method 2
df %>% group_by(signals) %>% 
  mutate(ANOVA = map(data, ~fAddANOVA(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(ANOVA)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 9
# Groups:   signals [12]
   signals     data              Effect   DFn   DFd     F     p `p<.05`      ges
   <chr>       <list>            <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
 1 P3FCz       <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 0.012 0.988 ""      0.000338
 2 P3Cz        <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 0.228 0.797 ""      0.006   
 3 P3Pz        <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 1.61  0.207 ""      0.043   
 4 LPPearlyFCz <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 0.885 0.417 ""      0.024   
 5 LPPearlyCz  <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 2.65  0.077 ""      0.069   
 6 LPPearlyPz  <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 4.62  0.013 "*"     0.114   
 7 LPP1FCz     <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 1.08  0.344 ""      0.029   
 8 LPP1Cz      <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 2.45  0.094 ""      0.064   
 9 LPP1Pz      <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 3.97  0.023 "*"     0.099   
10 LPP2FCz     <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 0.103 0.903 ""      0.003   
11 LPP2Cz      <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 0.446 0.642 ""      0.012   
12 LPP2Pz      <tibble [75 x 5]> COND       2    72 1.17  0.316 ""      0.031
```

And for tTest

```
#Add pairwise_t_test
fAddtTest = function(data) data %>% 
  pairwise_t_test(value~COND, paired = TRUE,
                  p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

#Method 1
df %>% group_by(signals) %>% 
  group_modify(~fAddtTest(.x$data[[1]]))

#Method 2
df %>% group_by(signals) %>% 
  mutate(tTest = map(data, ~fAddtTest(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(tTest)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 36 x 12
# Groups:   signals [12]
   signals     data              .y.   group1  group2     n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.adj p.adj.signif
   <chr>       <list>            <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1 P3FCz       <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC    25    25   -0.322     24 0.75  1     ns          
 2 P3FCz       <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC    25    25   -0.178     24 0.86  1     ns          
 3 P3FCz       <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC    25    25    0.112     24 0.911 1     ns          
 4 P3Cz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC    25    25   -0.624     24 0.539 1     ns          
 5 P3Cz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC    25    25    0.592     24 0.559 1     ns          
 6 P3Cz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC    25    25    0.925     24 0.364 1     ns          
 7 P3Pz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC    25    25    0.440     24 0.664 1     ns          
 8 P3Pz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEU-NOC    25    25    3.11      24 0.005 0.014 *           
 9 P3Pz        <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-NOC NEU-NOC    25    25    2.43      24 0.023 0.069 ns          
10 LPPearlyFCz <tibble [75 x 5]> value NEG-CTR NEG-NOC    25    25   -0.0919    24 0.928 1     ns          
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Now is the time to create a boxplot

```
#Function to special boxplot
SpecBoxplot = function(data, autor = "G. Anonim"){
box = data %>% ggboxplot(x = "COND", y = "value", add = "point")
pwc = data %>% 
  pairwise_t_test(value~COND, paired = TRUE,
                  p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") %>% 
  add_xy_position(x = "COND")
res.aov = data %>% anova_test(value~COND)
data %>% 
  ggboxplot(x = "COND", y = "value", add = "point") + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(pwc) +
  labs(
    title = get_test_label(res.aov, detailed = TRUE),
    subtitle = get_pwc_label(pwc),
    caption = autor
  )
}  

#special boxplot for the P3FCz signal
df$data[[1]] %>% SpecBoxplot()
 
#A function that creates a special boxplot and adds it to a data frame
AddSignalBoxplot = function(df, signal, printPlot=TRUE) {
  plot = SpecBoxplot(df$data[[1]], signal)
  if(printPlot) print(plot)
  df %>% mutate(boxplot = list(plot))
}

#Added special boxplot
df %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  group_modify(~AddSignalBoxplot(.x, .y))
```

[image]

Due to the inconsistency with the normal distribution in the modified function, I used the Wilcoxon test for comparison. I also improved the boxplots a bit.

```
#Function to special boxplot2
SpecBoxplot2 = function(data, signal, autor = "G. Anonim"){
  pwc = data %>% pairwise_wilcox_test(value~COND) %>%
    add_xy_position(x = "COND") %>% 
    mutate(COND="NEG-CTR",
           lab = paste(p, " - ", p.adj.signif))
  
  data %>% ggplot(aes(COND, value, fill=COND))+
    geom_violin(alpha=0.2)+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 23,
                 outlier.size = 3,
                 alpha=0.6)+
    geom_jitter(shape=21, width =0.1)+
    stat_pvalue_manual(pwc, step.increase=0.05, label = "lab")+
    labs(title = signal,
         subtitle = get_pwc_label(pwc),
         caption = autor)
}

#special boxplot for the P3FCz signal
df$data[[1]] %>% SpecBoxplot2("P3FCz")

#A function that creates a special boxplot2 and adds it to a data frame
AddSignalBoxplot2 = function(df, signal, printPlot=TRUE) {
  plot = SpecBoxplot2(df$data[[1]], signal)
  if(printPlot) print(plot)
  df %>% mutate(boxplot = list(plot))
}

#Added special boxplot2
df %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  group_modify(~AddSignalBoxplot2(.x, .y))
```

[image]

**Special update fom my frend**

Hey @mały_statystyczny! You will be great!

Here is a special update for you. Below is a function that prepares graphs with both parametric and non-parametric statistics.

```
#Function to special boxplot3
SpecBoxplot3 = function(data, signal, parametric = FALSE, autor = "G. Anonim"){
  if(parametric) {
    pwc = data %>%
      pairwise_t_test(value~COND, paired = TRUE,
                      p.adjust.method = "bonferroni") %>%
      add_xy_position(x = "COND") %>%
      mutate(COND="NEG-CTR",
             lab = paste(p, " - ", p.adj.signif))
    res.test = data %>% anova_test(value~COND)
  } else {
    pwc = data %>% pairwise_wilcox_test(value~COND) %>%
      add_xy_position(x = "COND") %>%
      mutate(COND="NEG-CTR",
             lab = paste(p, " - ", p.adj.signif))
    res.test = data %>% kruskal_test(value~COND)
  }
  
  data %>% ggplot(aes(COND, value, fill=COND))+
    geom_violin(alpha=0.2)+
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = 23,
                 outlier.size = 3,
                 alpha=0.6)+
    geom_jitter(shape=21, width =0.1)+
    stat_pvalue_manual(pwc, step.increase=0.05, label = "lab")+
    ylab(signal)+
    labs(title = get_test_label(res.test, detailed = TRUE),
         subtitle = get_pwc_label(pwc),
         caption = autor)
}


#special boxplot for the P3FCz signal
df$data[[1]] %>% SpecBoxplot3("P3FCz", TRUE)
df$data[[1]] %>% SpecBoxplot3("P3FCz", FALSE)

#A function that creates a special boxplot3 and adds it to a data frame
AddSignalBoxplot3 = function(df, signal, printPlot=TRUE) {
  plot1 = SpecBoxplot3(df$data[[1]], signal, TRUE)
  plot2 = SpecBoxplot3(df$data[[1]], signal, FALSE)
  if(printPlot) print(plot1)
  if(printPlot) print(plot2)
  df %>% mutate(boxplot1 = list(plot1),
                boxplot2 = list(plot2),
  )
}

#Added special boxplot3
df %>% group_by(signals) %>%
  group_modify(~AddSignalBoxplot3(.x, .y))
```

Here are the results of its operation
[image]

[image]

Comment: You changed your mind about my solutions, but later converted. I appreciate it ;-)   I also encourage you to read [this](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_nonparametric/bs704_nonparametric_print.html). I found it for you!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)
library(readxl)

data <- read_excel("df_join.xlsx")

n <- ncol(data)-4

lAnovas <- map(1:n, ~ anova_test(
  data = data.frame(data[,c(1,4)], data[,.x+4]) %>% 
    setNames(c("ID", "COND", names(data)[.x+4])), 
  dv = !!names(data)[.x+4], wid = ID, within = COND) %>% 
  get_anova_table())

lPwc <- map(1:n, ~ data %>%
      pairwise_t_test(
        formula(
          paste0(names(data)[.x+4]," ~ COND")),
        paired = TRUE,
        p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"
      )
)

lPwc <- map(lPwc, ~ .x %>% add_xy_position(x = "COND"))

drawbox <-  function(x)
{
  ggboxplot(data = data, 
            x = "COND", y = names(data)[x+4], add = "point") + 
    stat_pvalue_manual(lPwc[[x]]) +
    labs(
      subtitle = get_test_label(lAnovas[[x]], detailed = TRUE),
      caption = get_pwc_label(lPwc[[x]]) 
    )
}

walk(1:n, ~ drawbox(.x) %>% print())
```

Answer (score 0):

After running the code as it is I obtain this arrangement:

```
A tibble: 12 x 2
   signals     anova         
 * <fct>       <list>        
 1 P3FCz       <anov_tst [3]>
 2 P3Cz        <anov_tst [3]>
 3 P3Pz        <anov_tst [3]>
 4 LPPearlyFCz <anov_tst [3]>
 5 LPPearlyCz  <anov_tst [3]>
 6 LPPearlyPz  <anov_tst [3]>
 7 LPP1FCz     <anov_tst [3]>
 8 LPP1Cz      <anov_tst [3]>
 9 LPP1Pz      <anov_tst [3]>
10 LPP2FCz     <anov_tst [3]>
11 LPP2Cz      <anov_tst [3]>
12 LPP2Pz      <anov_tst [3]>
```

And I can access to the anova statistic through this command (for instance for the first elemnt of the list):

```
res.aov[[2]][[1]][["ANOVA"]]
  Effect DFn DFd     F     p p<.05      ges
1   COND   2  48 0.044 0.957       0.000338
```

Anyway that unnested_aov shoud contain exactly a list with this anova statistics for each element.I would need for some code to get_label from this list and the postHocs one for creating graphs. If you have other idea, you can share that.

Comment: Your results are different from yours. So, to have both running the *exactly* the same code, I would suggest you to send me it by e-mail. My e-mail address is on my profile.

Comment: Ok, I've sent you an email. Just let e know whether you have it received.

Comment: Got it! I am now going to send you an e-mail.

Comment: Replied you back. ;)